# Exporting R result to CSV or tab delimited format for using in Tassel

Tags: r

I want to prepare my phenotypic trait file in R for using in the Tassel program.  When I save the results in format of CSV or tab delimited file, R will add a column with an ordinal number which in fact is the column 0 in R dataframe as it is shown in the picture. Then after when I open the file in the Tassel, it cannot open the file and give me error. The error is due to the column which is added.
 How should I eliminate this column in my CSV or tab delimited format?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuDXS.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tAWF.jpg]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is really due to this supplementary column, use the argument removing the row names :

```
write.csv(tassel, "tt.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

See `?write.csv`

> row.names:
>   either a logical value indicating whether the row names of x are to be written along with x, or a character vector of row names to be written.

Comment: The problem is that, R import column zero in the file, as i showed in the picture